# Database Project to Drop Database before deploy?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, drop-database

Is it possible to get VS to drop the destination database before a deploy?

I've tried adding a post deploy script to the project, but it always comes back with active connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to look up the `Always recreate database` option in the properties of the database project -> Deploy -> Deployment configuration file -> Edit Dialog.

Another option "Drop objects that exist in the target database but not in the schema" can also be useful to you.

Comment: Just what I was looking, as always they do it first :) Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes there's more to it... check last reply of 'noonie' on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/184af3b8-e24f-4156-8c93-4870aaed039c. "And I've found out why you are getting the drop database in your script. If you have not set a Target connection (or subsequently cleared the previous setting) the deploy process adds the drop & create statements to the .sql file regardless of the setting in the Database.sqldeployment file."

Comment: I'm not seeing this in VS 2019. Where is the setting?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `Always re-create database` option under publish.

DB Project -> Right Click -> Publish -> Advanced

[image]